# Where is the app Personal Folder path

Tags: android, visual-studio, sqlite, permissions, xamarin.android

Im trying to create a sqlLite db. This code works and create the db and allow me do insert and select.

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), 
                                 "ormdemo.db3");

//dbPath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ormdemo.db3";

var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
db.CreateTable<Stock>();
```

Right now the dbPath returned is:

```
"/data/user/0/MyFirstGPSApp.MyFirstGPSApp/files/ormdemo.db3"
```

But when I use a sqlLite Manager to try open the db I cant find the folder `/data/user`

**Where is that folder `/data/user`?**

The sqlLite have the option to open "APP" databases, but when try to select `MyFirstGPSApp` say need a root device.

The starting folder for sqlLite is `/storage/emulated/0` and have a sub folder `/DCIM`

So I try to use a folder I can see ... like `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ormdemo.db3` but then the `new SQLiteConnection(dbPath)` give me this error.

> SQLite.SQLiteException: Could not open database file: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ormdemo.db3 (CannotOpen)

**Do I need special permision to write in `/DCIM` folder?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there are three questions in your post. Before answer your questions, I think some pictures are necessary.

P1:
[image]

P2:
[image]

Like @Yogesh Paliyal has said, you need `File Explorer` to see it. If you also want to see it and you don't want to root you device, please follow me: `Visual Studio->Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor->select one simulator from Devices column->File Explorer`. I suggest you create a simulator which Api is below 21, because the higher also can't see the file. I am using 19 to see the files.

And I think you should read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/949659/how-can-i-access-storage-emulated-0-dcim-on-android-device) firstly.

---

Ok, let's see your questions:

> Where is the app Personal Folder path?

In android, there are two folder: personal/internal folder and public/external folder, [here is official document](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html).

Personal/Internal Folder path:

- /data/data/package name/shared_prefs: [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
- /data/data/package name/databases: [Sqlite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)
- /data/data/package name/files: [Api:getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html)
- /data/data/package name/cache:  [Api:getCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html)
- /storage/sdcard/Android/data/package name/files: [Api:getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html)
- /storage/sdcard/Android/data/package name/cache: [Api:getExternalCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html)

Public/External Folder path:

- In `/storage/sdcard` folder, only `Android` folder is personal/internal folder,so `/storage/sdcard/DCIM`, `/storage/sdcard/Music`,etc, all of them are public/external folder: [Api:Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

> Where is that folder /data/user?

From P1, you can see the `->/data/data/` is behind of `/data/user/0`, so the folder `/data/user/0/MyFirstGPSApp.MyFirstGPSApp/files/ormdemo.db3`  is `/data/data/MyFirstGPSApp.MyFirstGPSApp/files/ormdemo.db3` actually.

> Do I need special permision to write in /DCIM folder?

Personal/Internal folder doesn't need permission, public/external folder need permission.

In `/storage/sdcard` folder, only `Android` folder is personal/internal folder, so you need permission:`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` or `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` or both.

Comment: so when in my phone I open the sqlLite mannager and show me `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/` what that mean? and why I cant create the database there ?

Comment: [Have you read this?](https://superuser.com/questions/949659/how-can-i-access-storage-emulated-0-dcim-on-android-device), and you need permission.

Comment: What permission I need? I read the link. I learn a few things. If I use sqlLite manager I can create a new db in `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM` if I connect the phone to my pc I can access the same `/DCIM` folder but is under `//Storage Card/DCIM` not `emulate` or `storage` But I cant see the sqlLite db I just create even when I select show hidden files. I know is the same because in the subfolder `/DCIM/Camera` can see my pictures.

Comment: `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, have you add this permission in your project?

Comment: Ok, that solve creating the database in `/DCIM`. A follow up question: Do External Storage refer only to the microSD? In my case I have 32 gb internal memory and 32 gb of a microSD. But in my moto-g they are join together as a single drive.

Comment: By `microSD`, are you meaning SD card? If so, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see directly from mobile without root permissions. 
Try using Android Studio's File explorer feature.

Comment: Im using visual studio. Not sure if have a File Explorer tool. But what about the DCIM folder?