# Overwrite an uri in xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am working with some images in Xamarin.Android, I used below to open the file

```
 Intent = new Intent();
 Intent.SetType("image/*");
 Intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple,true);
 Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
 StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), code);
```

I am just compressing the file using `Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 90, fs);` where fs is a Stream to save the file. I want to overwrite the opened uri (like replacing the existing bitmap with the current one (bmp).

I want to do this in bulk.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: By `overwrite the opened uri`, what do you mean? Do you want to open the album, select some pictures and change them?

Comment: @Joe Lv   I want to open an image -> compress it and save it to the existing file ( as we open a txt file and do some modification and then saving it)

Comment: Please test my code and leave me a message.

Comment: It still picking up the `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures` in the sdcardPath. As you had enclosed the picture of file manager that shows 2 storage 1st is 11E3-2116 and 2nd is emulated. I want to create a file in this directory-> **11E3-2116**, as the name of it changes from device to device mine is **D660-18BD**, thats what I am tellng, it is considering the internal storage.

Comment: We can see this in various places like Camera, when the internal memory is full then, it is storing it in the external memory card.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Java.Lang;
using Android.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Graphics;
using System.IO;

namespace PictureCopr
{
    [Activity(Label = "PictureCopr", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        ImageView miv;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            miv = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.iv);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetType("image/*");
            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple, true);
            intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                ClipData clipData = data.ClipData;
                Uri uri = data.Data;
                if (null == uri)//multi
                {
                    List<Uri> list = new List<Uri>(clipData.ItemCount);
                    for (int i = 0; i < clipData.ItemCount; i++)
                    {
                        ClipData.Item itemAt = clipData.GetItemAt(i);
                        list.Add(itemAt.Uri);
                        Android.Util.Log.Error("uri", itemAt.Uri.ToString());

                        try
                        {
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(itemAt.Uri));

                            var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
                            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, i+"test.png");

                            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 90, stream);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Android.Util.Log.Error("Exception", e.Message);
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {// single
                    try
                    {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri));
                        var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
                        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, "test.png");
                        Android.Util.Log.Error("lv====", filePath);
                        var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 90, stream);
                        stream.Flush();
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Android.Util.Log.Error("Exception", e.Message);
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Error("MainActivtiy", "operation error");
            }
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }
    }
}
```

### Update :

Replace this:

```
var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, i+"test.png");
```

with this:

```
var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures);
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath.AbsolutePath, i+"test.png");
```

---

### Update:

Write to Sd card demo:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.IO;
using Java.IO;

namespace WritToSd
{
    [Activity(Label = "WritToSd", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            if (IsSdCardExist())
            {
                Java.IO.File sdCardPath = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures);
                //  destPath: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/test.png
                string destPath = Path.Combine(sdCardPath.AbsolutePath, "test.png");
                string originPath = Path.Combine(sdCardPath.AbsolutePath, "nULSa.png");
                Android.Util.Log.Error("lv", destPath);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destPath , false);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(originPath);
                int b;
                byte[] d = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                while ((b = fis.Read(d)) != -1)
                {
                    fos.Write(d, 0, b);
                }
                fos.Flush();
                fos.Close();
                fis.Close();

            }
            else {
                //do something
            }

        }

        public  bool IsSdCardExist()
        {
            return Environment.ExternalStorageState.Equals(
                    Environment.MediaMounted);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This picture is the result.]

[This is nULSa.png picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nULSa.png])

Comment: `var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;` create file in the internal storage of the device, where as I had picked the uri that is in external SD storage. how can I replace that?

Comment: The `sdCardPath` is External Storage, you need permission. Where do you want to save the file?

Comment: The AbsolutePath is "/storage/D660-18BD/Amit/Images/IMG321.jpg". When I tried to create a file, it says Access to the path `"/storage/D660-18BD/Amit/Images/IMG321IR.jpg" is denied.`.

Comment: I am using Mashmallow (physical device). How can I take permission to write on the external SD Card (from where user has picked the Uri)

Comment: already did that but no luck. Reading/Writing from the internal storage is fine but when user picked the file from external sd card, then I can still read the file but unable to write to that path. I searched a lot but couldn't able to find the solution.

Comment: I have update my answer, please try again. I have try it Api19 and Api25, not M.

Comment: Still it fetches `{/storage/emulated/0/Pictures}` **INTERNAL STORAGE** in the sdCardPath, it requires to be `/storage/D660-18BD/Pictures, `

Comment: Look at the enclosed pictures [1][https://i.stack.imgur.com/nULSa.png] 
  [2][ https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQKR6.png]. I picked from the external sd card having absolutepath = "/storage/D660-18BD/Amit/Images/IMG321.jpg", I want to create a new file in this path `"/storage/D660-18BD/Amit/Images/IMG321IR.jpg"` but fails due to permission.

Comment: You must write the picture in `/storage/D660-18BD/Amit/Images` folder? I haven't use this path. Why not `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures`? There is file read/write restriction in Android. [Here is the document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html?). If you have the root permission, I think you can write it.

Comment: Suppose there is no free memory in internal memory and user wants to compress it pictures that are located in external sd card then what will be the solution?

Comment: Do you mean  this path `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures` is Internal Storage?

Comment: [I have this answer, please take a look at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191065/where-is-the-app-personal-folder-path/48202511#48202511)

Comment: Yeah `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures` is Internal Storage, my issue can also be resolved when I can able to write to the external SD card (not the internal memory). The link doesn't help much.

Comment: [Please refer to this again](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html?#filesExternal),  `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures` is not Internal Storage.

Comment: [And this](https://o7planning.org/en/10541/android-external-storage-tutorial), you can use `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures` to write the picture by `Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures);`, and you need add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, you need [`Requesting Permissions at Run Time`](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?), because  M is 6.0.

Comment: [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?)

Comment: As picture enclosed in the earlier comment, you can look that I have 2 storage (Internal and other is SD Card (Removable media).

Comment: I have seen it. Let's solve your problem, have you requested permission at run time?

Comment: Yes, I requested permission for Read/Write External storage alongwith `var takeFlags = ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission;
                GrantUriPermission(PackageName, SourceUri, takeFlags);
                ContentResolver.TakePersistableUriPermission(SourceUri, takeFlags);`

Comment: I possible can you post a small prototype that can write file to external SD card? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not this, [`this is request permission at run time`](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/)

Comment: What about tomorrow? I need have dinner, it is 8.20 pm.

Comment: I already tried that before. O Sure, thank you for you patience.