# Add asset dynamically in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm beginning in Xamarin and I'm currently playing with assets.
What I would like to do is a small app that can read an xml file.

If the file is in the APK natively, there is no problem, but, what I would to do is to be able to read a file that I downloaded from internet.

Where should I put the file? How can I access it?

The aim is to create an app in which the user can download a "book" and read it whenever (s)he wants.

Bonus point, the file would be accessible only from the app :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you download a file, you should save it to the device:

```
string path = Application.Context.FilesDir.Path;
var filePath = Path.Combine(path, "Nineteen-Eighty-Four.xml");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, contentOfYourXmlFile);
```

Then you can read the content of your file as below:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

To keep track of paths to your files/books, you need to also store them. You could just store them in Preferences, but I'd advise to store them in a local database. You can read about different options for Xamarin Android [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/). You can start by creating a simple table in SQLite like below:

```
public class Book
{
     [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
     public int ID { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     public string Author { get; set; }

     public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Please take a look for full android SQLite example here: [Create a Database with SQLite](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/)

Above examples of saving/reading files were taken from [Data Storage Using Xamarin](https://www.developer.com/ws/android/data-storage-using-xamarin.html). Above example writes the file to a location accessible only for your application.

Comment: The books are large files, so dont save it in Internal storage. The file path should be `/storage/sdcard/Android/data/package name/files`, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191065/where-is-the-app-personal-folder-path/48202511#48202511)